# Passing json objects to a bottle template correctly

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, bottle

I'm using bottle and d3.js to display some data. I'm using bottle to get the data and to pass it to to the template file:

```
from bottle import run
from bottle import template
import json

app = Bottle()


@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    # .... code to read and clean the data
    my_data = [{"name": "my name", "parent": "null", "children": "children"}]
    return template('tree', package=json.dumps(my_data))


run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The .tpl file is:

```
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var treeData = {{!package}};

//some javascript to display the data

// ************** Generate the tree diagram      ***************** 
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The line

```
root.x0 = height / 2;
```

is throwing an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating root.x0 = height / 2)`. The code for this tree comes from:  http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092. There the data structure `treeData` is defined as:

```
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
        "children"
    ]
  }
];
```

But in my browser the son has been serialised (or at least it appears as) as:

```
var treeData = {"name": "my name", "parent": "null", "children": "children"}
```

How can I sort this out? I'm always going to pass a json object - either a dict, or a list of dicts. The example works fine if I replace

```
var treeData = {{!package}}
```

with

```
var treeData = = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
        "children"
    ]
  }
];
```

directly in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this can be solved really easily by changing:

```
var treeData = {{!package}}
```

to

```
var treeData = [{{!package}}]
```